# Estoy realizando un ciclo for para una comparación entre dos dataframes, pero a la hora de comparar las fechas, no identifica la menor de ella

Tags: bucle-for, date, index

En mi código no logro hacer que cuando se encuentren las coincidencias dentro de dos dataframe al comparar dos datos de fecha elija de forma correcta la menor de ellas, para así posteriormente copiar los criterios que requiero del df2 y pegarlos en el df3, es decir, si una fecha es menor que otra dame estos datos y si no, dame otro dato.

Comment: if len(estatus_valido) > 3 and 'Recuperado con firma y sello(1)' in estatus_valido and 'No aplica(1)' in estatus_valido: \n
            fecha_rfs = row_data['FechaRfs'] \n
            fecha_na = row_data['FechaNA'] \n

            if pd.notnull(fecha_rfs) and pd.notnull(fecha_na): \n
                if fecha_rfs > fecha_na: \n
                    df3.loc[index, 'Estatus valido':'Hora EV'] = [row_data['Recuperado con firma y sello(1)'], \n
                                                                   row_data['FechaNA'], row_data['HoraNA']]

Comment: Para agregar código, debes [edit] tu pregunta. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.